# IS There any way to send values from JavaScript to Controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

OnClick Event of a button
the values enter by user inside Username and Password text boxes are successfully retrieved into the javaScript function, now I want to send these values to CodeIgniter controller
is there any way to do it???
thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You have to use ajax for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it with jquery...pretty simple.

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/site/addItems/'); ?>",
```

is pointing to a function in the controller

```
    $('#addItem').click(function(){
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var data = {
        item: $('#itemName').val(),
        price: $('#itemPrice').val(),
        id: $('#id').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/site/addItems/'); ?>",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#items').html(msg);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Of course you may always use native JS methods for AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp